# How to stay on same page after refreshing? rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am having few links in a page which redirects to different pages. If I click on 3rd link suppose and a page is displayed. Now if I refresh the page it is redirecting to the first link.

But according to my requirement it should be in the same page i.e on which link I clicked.
Can anyone tell me how achieve this functionality.

Here is the code:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#tabs-1">link-1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tabs-2">link-2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tabs-3">link-3</a></li>
</ul>
```

now if I click on link-3 and I am on link-3 page. now if I refresh the page I should be in the link-3 page. Instead I am redirected to link-1 on page refresh.

Comment: What you have described sounds suspicious. Can you plz share the code of your page?

Comment: you might have certain validation on the 3rd link action which will redirect you to the previous page. Otherwise its no possible.

Comment: all my pages contain only text. Pls find my edited query @chandrasnshu

Comment: Do you use javascript to change the page contents? Does your url change in the address toolbar as well?

Comment: Yes my url is changing but my pages are only having text to view. no changes are made in the pages. @nathanvda

Comment: The links you show are anchors. That should work with refreshes. Unless you are using javascript, e.g. to switch tabs, and it is only when clicking the links, and not when loading the page. So imho you are using javascript.

Comment: it seems he uses jqueryUIs tabs, i've posted a workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it seems like you're using jqueryUI tabs, you'll need to update the address bar after the activation event, so that the tab#id will appear over there:

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
  activate: function(event,ui) {
    var anchor = $(event.target).attr("id");
    location.hash = anchor; //this will add #id to your url, which upon refresh will trigger the jquery tab selection event
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Only way I can see this is possible is if you instead of refreshing the page manually by pressing F5 or similar actually have a meta refresh in page 3 which instructs your browser to automatically refresh and redirect after a given time amount. Have you written the page linked to by link3 yourself? If not, can you check the headers in page 3 for something like `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://example.com/">` ?